# org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element listFunctions has a relative namespace: xmlns="xxx_xxx_listFunctions"

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am new to `Axis2` and webservices. I have a axis2 web services. Things run fine when ws-security is turned off. When ws-security is turned on, I get the following exception in the server log. I debugged the service class method is not called. Attached are two service.xmls used.

The client invoking the webservice get the followoing soap fault - unexpected EOF in prolog

I get the following java exception in tomcat :

```
org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element listFunctions has a relative namespace: xmlns="test_vish_listFunctions"
    at org.apache.xml.security.c14n.implementations.Canonicalizer20010315.handleAttributesSubtree(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.c14n.implementations.CanonicalizerBase.canonicalizeSubTree(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.c14n.implementations.CanonicalizerBase.engineCanonicalizeSubTree(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.c14n.implementations.CanonicalizerBase.engineCanonicalizeSubTree(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer.canonicalizeSubtree(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.outputDOM(Unknown Source)
```

Following is the server.xml when ws-security is off and things works

```
    <service name="test_vish_listFunctions" targetNamespace="test_vish_listFunctions">
   <description>
        This service is to get the list  functions
   </description>
   <schema schemaNamespace="test_listFunctions"/>
   <parameter name="ServiceClass">vish.web.ws.service.ListFunctionsService</parameter>
   <operation name="listFunctions">
        <messageReceiver  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
   </operation>
   <module ref="soapmonitor"/>
 </service>
```

The following the services.xml when ws-security is turned on

```
<service name="test_vish_listRoutines" targetNamespace="test_vish_listRoutines">
   <description>Service description for test_vish_listRoutines</description>
  <schema schemaNamespace="test_vish_listRoutines"/>
  <parameter name="ServiceClass">test.web.ws.service.ListRoutinesService</parameter>
  <parameter name = "disasbleREST">true</parameter>
  <operation name="listRoutines">
  <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</operation>
<module ref="soapmonitor"/>
<module ref="rampart" />
<parameter name = "InflowSecurity"><action>
<items>UsernameToken</items>
<passwordCallbackClass>test.web.ws.control.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
</action>
</parameter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem and fixed the issue. The issue was not with Axis2.The exception as listed in my question relates to the way XML Security works. The services.xml in .aar file had targetNamespace="test_vish_listRoutines". The client code consuming the webservices with WS-Security set to true, was using this namespace. It was calling 'listRoutines', which  is a relative namespace and not allowed in standard XMLSecurity. On the serer side, the service method related to listRoutines was not getting called itself.

Changing is to a standard URL type namespace like 'http://www.testing.com/webserice solved the problem.

Sigh of relief atlast. Hope this helps

Comment: Saved my day !! I was applying spring wss4j interceptor and replacing the relative namepace uris worked like a charm